# Android webview client unable to load url if private DNS is enabled

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I have a Webview client that works fine usually but if I use a custom/private DNS it won't load any url.

`Error code = -6` `Error : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Other Browsers still work fine with DNS enabled.

I have internet permission and network state permission already added.

Any idea what could cause this? - I am trying this on Android 13.

tried different settings for webview like domstorage, cache, sslpreferences but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the WebView client uses the DNS resolver provided by the system, which may not be compatible with custom/private DNS settings.

Try setting a custom DNS resolver for your WebView client, following this example:

```
// Create a DNS resolver
DnsResolver dnsResolver = new DnsResolver() {
    @Override
    public List<InetAddress> resolve(String hostname) throws UnknownHostException {
        // Replace "your.custom.dns.server" with the IP address of your custom DNS server
        return Arrays.asList(InetAddress.getAllByName("your.custom.dns.server"));
    }
};

// Create a Network object with the custom DNS resolver
Network network = new Network() {
    @Override
    public InetAddress[] getAllByName(String hostname) throws UnknownHostException {
        return dnsResolver.resolve(hostname).toArray(new InetAddress[0]);
    }
};

// Create a WebView client and set the Network object
WebView webView = new WebView(context);
webView.setNetworkAvailable(true);
webView.setNetworkForUrl(network, "http://double.bang.op");
```

If this doesn't help, please post the relevant code snippet from your WebView client.

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. Did you get it working in the end?

@Introspective - I don't suppose you would happen to have this code in Kotlin?